# Solution verification: Showing that $\|A\|_\infty = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|$ for $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, normed-spaces

$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\| #1 \|}
\newcommand{\inorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_\infty}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\para}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$**Context:** This ultimately ties back to a homework assignment. (Specifically it's from *Fundamentals of Matrix Calculations* by Watkins, Exercise $2.1.30$ from $\S2.1$ but that's not really a huge deal, seems like a fairly common exercise.)

The goal is to show that, knowing matrix $p$-norms are induced by the corresponding vector norms, $\forall A \in \R^{n\times n}$,
$$\|A\|_\infty = \max \limits_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|$$
I have an approach and was just curious as to how valid it is; I just don't feel very sure of myself. I feel like I made some sort of small-yet-critical mistake somewhere, but I can't figure out where...

---

**My Attempt:**

Ultimately, we will show that

$$\max \limits_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| \le \|A\|_\infty \le \max \limits_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|$$

which will let me conclude with the desired equality ($a \le b \le a \implies a=b$).

From the definition of the $\infty$-norm, with $A := (a_{i,j})_{1 \le i,j \le n} \in \R^{n \times n}$ and $x := (x_i)_{1 \le i \le n} \in \R^n$,
$$
\inorm{Ax} = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \abs{ \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} x_k }
$$
Applying the triangle inequality yields
$$
\inorm{Ax} \le \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k} x_k|  = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| \cdot | x_k|
$$
Note that
$$
|x_k| \le \max_{1 \le j \le n} |x_j| =: \norm{x}_\infty
$$
and thus
$$
\inorm{Ax} \le  \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| \cdot \norm{x}_\infty 
$$
$\norm{x}_\infty$ is independent of $i$, so we factor it out and conclude
$$
\inorm{Ax} \le \norm{x}_\infty \para{ \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| }
$$
Thus,
$$
\inorm{A} = \max_{x \ne \vec 0} \frac{\inorm{Ax}}{\inorm{x}} \le \frac{\displaystyle \norm{x}_\infty \para{ \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| }}{\norm{x}_\infty} = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|
$$
Thus, with $\inorm{A}$ less than or equal to the desired expression, we need to find an $\hat x$ such that equality is achieved. Suppose in row $r$ the maximum is achieved; for every $k$, let
$$
\hat x_k = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{if } a_{r,k} \ge 0 \\
-1 & \text{if } a_{r,k} < 0
\end{cases} = \mathrm{sign}(a_{r,k})
$$
Define $\hat x := (\hat x_i)_{1 \le i \le n}$ as defined above; clearly $\inorm{\hat x}=1$. This ensures $a_{r,k}\hat x_k = |a_{r,k}|$. Then
\begin{align*}
\norm{A}_\infty
&=  \max_{x \ne \vec 0} \frac{\inorm{Ax}}{\inorm{x}}  \tag{def. of matrix norm} \\
&\ge \frac{\inorm{A \hat x}}{\inorm{\hat x}} \tag{def. of maximum}\\
&= \inorm{A \hat x} \tag{$\inorm{\hat x} = 1$} \\
&= \max_{1 \le i \le n} \abs{ \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} \hat x_k } \tag{definition}\\
&=  \abs{ \sum_{k=1}^n a_{r,k} \hat x_k } \tag{definition of $r$}\\
&=  \abs{ \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{r,k}| } \tag{choice of $\hat x_k$, $r$}\\
&=   \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{r,k}|  \tag{$|z| \ge 0 \implies \sum_i |z_i| \ge 0$}\\
&= \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| \tag{def. of $r$}
\end{align*}
Thus what we have seen is that
$$
\max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| \le \norm{A}_\infty \le \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|
$$
thus letting us conclude equality:
$$
\norm{A}_\infty = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|
$$

Comment: +1, lovely question! Are there one or two very specific steps or inequalities that you are unsure of above? If someone's writing an answer it will be more helpful to you if they elaborate on why that particular step is right or wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an issue. In the part of showing $\big\lVert A \big\rVert_\infty \geq \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|$ you've write the equality$$
\max_{1 \le i \le n}  \Bigg\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} \hat x_k \Bigg\rvert 
=  \Bigg\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{r,k} \hat x_k   \Bigg\rvert 
$$

is true because of the definition of $r$. Recall that $r$ is taken as an  integer between $1$ and $n$ such that $$\max_{1\leq i\leq n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}|= \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{r,k}|$$holds, so the equality does not follow immediately. I think it would be better to write as follows:

\begin{align*}
& \max_{1 \le i \le n} \Bigg\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} \hat x_k \Bigg\rvert \\
& \geq  \Bigg\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{r,k} \hat x_k \Bigg\rvert \tag{definition of maximum}\\
&=  \Bigg\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{r,k}| \Bigg\rvert \tag{choice of $\hat x_k$, $r$}\\
&=   \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{r,k}|  \\
&= \max_{1 \le i \le n} \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{i,k}| \tag{definition of $r$}
\end{align*}
Other parts seem good to me.